# Extract day, month, year from date in Oracle

Tags: oracle

```
while currdate <= enddate
    LOOP
    --  dayz := extract(day from currdate);
    insert into pf_dim_photo_period(per_id,day_nbr_fisc_yr) values(x,dayz);
    currdate := currdate + 1;
    x := x + 1;
    END LOOP;
```

I am trying to populate the table with dates for 5 years in 1 column; then extract the day, year and month from the currdate variable to populate 3 other columns in the table.

However, if I uncomment my extract() line in the code, only the start date of each month is getting populated in the table. If I uncomment that line, all dates are populated, but I need this to work. What am I doing wrong here? How can I extract the day, month and year? Please help.

Comment: I don't understand what you're seeing or how to replicate it. Calling `extract()` doesn't modify `currdate`, and if I do the same thing in a loop it gets all the dates as expected. Can you turn this into a complete standalone block that demonstrates the problem you're having?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, Alex. I was able to successfully extract year and month from the same variable. Only when I do day, it shows day 1 of the month, then skips the rest of the month and shows day 1 of the following month. I don't think I understand what you mean when you ask me for a standalone block. My code above is standalone; I am not trying to do anything else there.

Comment: Sorry, I may have been unclear last week. My output is actually Aug1, Sep1, Oct1, then Aug2, Sep2, Oct2 and so on. I expect Aug1, Aug2, Aug3... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: [This SQl Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f15563/1) creates all the days, using extract, for a smaller range. I don't understand your last comment though; you have all the data but in the wrong order? How are you querying it?

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, something wrong with how I was looking at it. All good now. I have one question - if I need to extract the day and then update the table with the day of the year, how do I do it? For example, if the date is Feb 2, then the day must be stored as 33. If Jan 31, then 31.

Comment: With `to_number(to_char(currdate, 'DDD'))`. [More on format models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212). You can almost certainly do all of this, including inserting records for all the dates, without any PL/SQL; but that's a bit beyond the scope.